# Get a number as many as the user inputed

Tags: python

I have a task to make an output program like this

```
if input : 5
then output : 2,6,10,14,18
```

Output must as many of total number as the input

My previous code like this

```
n = 5
num = 2
i = 1

while i <= n:
  if num % 2 == 0:
    if num % 4 != 0:
      print(num)
  i = i+1
  num = num+1
```

But my output was just 2 numbers, i should get 5 numbers.

```
2,6
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should only increment `i` when you `print(num)`

Comment: Where do you define the variable "bil" ?

Comment: @AndrewJouffray oh sorry, bil = num

Answer (score 1):

Put the i+1 under the second if condition

```
if num % 4 != 0:
  print(num)
  i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
As you can see your output is following the Arithmetic progression

#### first number
a = 2 
#### diffrence between the seq numbers
d = 4
#### number of terms in sequence
n = 5 

### running loop n times
### a + (n-1) * d ( geeting the nth didgit in AP `enter code here`)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(2 + (i-1)*d , end=',')
```